# how to set password on apk uninstall when the user tried to uninstall our app

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. which is a children activity tracker parents can track the activities of their children, for that reason i want my app to run forever and the child can not uninstall it's only the parents who knows the password can uninstall the app. I Searched this on the internet some says its not possible and some says its possible some antivirus apps has this feature like McAfee etc i want to add this functionality in which i want to restrict user to uninstall the android app by password, at the time of app installation i want to get input password from user and during uninstallation user must enter the same password to uninstall it. without entering that password he should not uninstall the app.
please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Require a password to uninstall/remove application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221534/require-a-password-to-uninstall-remove-application)

Comment: maybe because i need the same functionality in my app