# android: require password when uninstall app

Tags: android, authentication, passwords, uninstallation

I want to build app like parental control, so when child try to uninstall/remove my app I would like to require that a user type a password before being allowed to uninstall/remove my application.

i try this, but still don't understand :
[Require a password to uninstall/remove application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221534/require-a-password-to-uninstall-remove-application)

Any suggest?

Comment: I am not a negative man...but I believe its impossible

Comment: in a standard device, every thing application related is managed by Android's package manager...if it was that easy to hide apps and stuff then there could be world war III

Comment: Or maybe hide this application when installed, Can i do that??

Comment: owhh, okay thank's Sean for your attention

Comment: I think there is only one which is you need to root your device to do so otherwise its impossible.

Comment: @RIT: So, if i root my device, it's possible to do that??

Comment: Android firmware modifications allow it as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

You can lock the device if you use device administration. Users can't uninstall active device admins, then you can lock the device if they try to disable device admin, then the parent could type in the password to unlock it.

**Warning:** This could be considered malicious, if your user isn't VERY well informed of how this will work. Review the Terms & Conditions for whatever app store you're releasing on, in case this behavior isn't allowed.

In your manifest:

```
  <receiver android:name=".AdminReceiver"
        android:label="Administration"
        android:description="@string/descript"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                       android:resource="@xml/deviceadmin" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Then in `@xml/deviceadmin`

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-policies>
    <reset-password />
    <force-lock />
  </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Then

```
public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
@Override
        public CharSequence onDisableRequested(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            
            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(startMain); //switch to the home screen, not totally necessary
            lockPhone(context, secPassword);
            //Log.i(TAG, "DEVICE ADMINISTRATION DISABLE REQUESTED & LOCKED PHONE");
            
            return "haha. i locked your phone.";
        }
    public static boolean lockPhone(Context context, String password){
        devAdminReceiver = new ComponentName(context, AdminReceiver.class);
        dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        boolean pwChange = dpm.resetPassword(password, 0);
        dpm.lockNow();
        return pwChange;
    }   
}
```

To enable your app as a device administrator:

```
devAdminReceiver = new ComponentName(context, AdminReceiver.class);
        dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        dpm.isAdminActive(devAdminReceiver);
```

Comment: sorry, but i really confuse. Where i create `@xml/deviceadmin`, i mean in manifest or layout? please . . Help me

Comment: Create a folder named `xml` in `res`, then create a file named `deviceadmin.xml`

Comment: how it works?, sorry but i still confused. when user try to uninstall this app, and then dialog box will show up to ask password. Like that??

Comment: No. 1) Child tries to uninstall and it says "You must disable device admin to uninstall." 2) Child goes to Security > Device Administrators and chooses to disable Device Administration for your app. 3) The phone automatically locks to the device's regular lock screen (with a password). 4) Child has to get parent to enter the password.

Comment: i have two class now, MainActivity and AdminReceiver. In adminReceiver the cotents as you wrote above. So, how to call it in MainActivity??

Comment: The last block of code is how you enable Device Administration. Alternatively, you can go to Security > Device Administrators and enable it from there. If you were still able to uninstall the app, you either did something wrong OR did not enable Device Administration.

Comment: you have some example in Android Project or apk? Please help me, i really need it

Comment: No I don't. For the sake of problem solving/learning, I would suggest you take what I gave you and try your best to make it work. If you try to implement it all and you're getting errors or a specific problem with it and you can't figure it out, then you can post a new question on SO. Good luck.

Comment: owhh, Ok . I will post a new question later. Thank you very much . .

Comment: A reader has tried to get in touch with you to ask about your solution here, Jakar (via an answer on this page, now mod-deleted). Would you have [a read](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32529633/472495)?