# Require password when unistall an app in android

Tags: authentication, android-intent, passwords, uninstallation, password-protection

Hey i want when user is trying to un-install an app ,there comes password to unlock. Im following this code :

[android: require password when uninstall app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995553/android-require-password-when-uninstall-app)

but there comes an error in manifest "android:description="@string/descript""
Kindly help me.im badly stuck in it.there's no answer availble on google too

Comment: This is potentially the _worst_ idea I've ever heard. It may be that you have a good reason for it but, if I couldn't get rid of some crapware because it required a password, I seriously consider tracking down the author for some "re-education" as to who actually _owns_ my device :-)

Comment: its a parental app like if child want to unistall an app,he cant and need his parent to unlock this

Comment: As per my comment on another question: examine the device every so often. If the app is gone, the kid loses it for a day. Next time a week. Then a month. They'll soon learn not to mess around with the oldies :-)

Comment: lol yeah u r right but i have to do this task cause its my job task :(

Comment: No, that's okay, if it's your job, it's your job. Wish I could help you out further, best of luck.

Comment: can you please recommend or refer someone to whom i take help regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    try the following code in your service 
    public static final String UNINSTALLER ="com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity";
private ActivityManager activityManager = null;
private ExecutorService executorService;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    LockerThread thread = new LockerThread();
    executorService.submit(thread);
}

   private void protactApp(String packname) {
            Intent pwdIntent = null;
            pwdIntent = new Intent("uninstaller.receiver");
            sendBroadcast(pwdIntent);


        }
class LockerThread implements Runnable {

    private String lastname;

    public LockerThread() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

            ComponentName act = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;
            String packname = act.getPackageName();



            if (act.getClassName().equals(UNINSTALLER)) {
                Log.d("Tag", "package to be uninstalled");
                protactApp(UNINSTALLER);
            }
        }
```

and from receiver you can get action while uninstall the app so whatever screen you prepare for password or pattern that you can start before uninstall like applock application

Comment: what is uninstaller.receiver? a class or build in something?

Comment: that is your custom broad cast same like we get action by intent filter this is custom broadcast

Comment: how we get action in receiver?

Comment: there is no need to define action filter in manifest you will get action in your receiver

@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  String[] packageNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("android.intent.extra.PACKAGES");

  Log.d("Tag", "onReceive of uninstall intent");

 }

Comment: what is the code i write in onRecieve of broadcast receiver?

Comment: @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        c=context;
        Toast.makeText(c,"ON Received",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, " onReceive !!!!." + "PACKAGE_REMOVED",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

Comment: there you can write the code for start lock service which will open the lock screen

Comment: and yeah one another thing to remember is always create a REBOOT receiver so when your phone is shutting down and start than your service will again started

Comment: when i cicked on unistall button , log is not showing

Comment: have you register receiver ?

<receiver android:name="com.package.receiver.RebootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Answer (score 0):

it would not help on 4.3 or higher but I am posting a link where you can find the solution and reason of why you can not do it. 
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756180/ask-for-password-before-uninstalling-application). Hope it would help you in understanding the real milestone in this context.